# Why are Google Analytics Values being passed on a form submit?

Tags: forms, cookies, get, google-analytics

My company's app builds simple forms that people can use on their websites to get information into our app.  We have a generic form response script that each of these forms submits to, to gather and parse the webform responses.

We're encountering form values that look a lot like the values in Google Analytics cookies (utmz, utmsc, utmccn)  The cookies are clearly not part of the form fields.  The form is being done with a simple HTML form submit, so I'm at a loss how these values are getting appended on to the post.

Here's a sample form submission:

```
http://website.com/submit.php?&clientGuid=2342342abcde23423423&webformid=12&prospect_id=12345&custom_Register_or_Dance_the_Chicken=Register&__utma=84164169.205192989.1344888984.1346176569.1346178936.47&__utmc=84164169&__utmz=84164169.1344888984.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
```

Under what circumstances would a browser submit cookies along with a form submit?  Is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like cross-domain user tracking... From the Google Analytics docs for [_linkByPost()](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_gat.GA_Tracker_._linkByPost):

> The [_linkByPost()](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_gat.GA_Tracker_._linkByPost) method passes the GATC cookies from the referring form to another site in a string appended to the action value of the form (HTTP POST).

If there's no `onsubmit='...'` code directly on the form, it might be attached  via jQuery or some other method.

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to Google Chrome adding them to your form variables on submission...